# Pgfplots: How to make the plot exceed the axes

Tags: pgfplots, formatting, plot, technical-drawing

I am plotting a spike using pgfplots. I want to make the y-axis until (4) only. However I want the plot of the spike itself to continue beyond the y-axis (say until 10).

Is there a possible way to do this? This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Style/.style={
width=4.5cm, height=5.8cm,
axis x line=center, 
axis y line=middle, 
samples=300,
ymin=-1, ymax=6,
xmin=-1, xmax=4,
domain=-1:4,
 }}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[font=\scriptsize,every axis legend/.append style={ legend pos=north east,font=\scriptsize},
  Axis Style,
  ytick={-1,1,2,3},yticklabels={$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$},
  xtick={-1,1,2,3},xticklabels={$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$},
  xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y=\frac{x(x-3.01)}{x-3}$},
  xticklabel shift=9pt,
  legend style={draw=none},
  tick style={color=black},
  x label style={anchor=west},
  y label style={anchor=south west} ]
  \addplot plot[mark=none,  thick, black] (\x,{(\x)/(\x-3)*(\x-3.01)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see **compilable code**, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `clip=false` does it.

Comment: thanks for answering,
Where should I used this style attribute? for the axis?

Comment: never mind .. It is an axis style ... thanks for the help :))

Answer (score 2):

The option `clip=false` does what you want.

Further improvement and control over the actual plot can give the keys `restrict y to domain`, `unbounded coords`, `samples` and `samples at`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{Axis Style/.style={
  width=4.5cm, height=5.8cm,
  axis x line=center, 
  axis y line=middle, 
  samples=300,
  ymin=-1, ymax=6,
  xmin=-1, xmax=4,
  domain=-1:4,
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[font=\scriptsize,every axis legend/.append style={ legend pos=north east,font=\scriptsize},
  Axis Style,
  ytick={-1,1,2,3},yticklabels={$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$},
  xtick={-1,1,2,3},xticklabels={$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$},
  xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y=\frac{x(x-3.01)}{x-3}$},
  xticklabel shift=9pt,
  legend style={draw=none},
  tick style={color=black},
  x label style={anchor=west},
  y label style={anchor=south west},
  clip=false,
  restrict y to domain=-1:17,
  unbounded coords=jump
   ]
  \addplot plot[mark=none, samples=1000, thick, black] (\x,{(\x)/(\x-3)*(\x-3.01)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]